# Facebook Test User API: disable secure browsing

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-test-users

I'd like to disable the "secure browsing" option for my generated facebook test users (via the test user api), so they can access my app (in sandbox mode) even though it runs on a local server without https.

Any idea if and how this could be archived?

And if it is possible, can I also modify the test users' other account settings e.g. privacy settings?